# Can I add/toggle Google maps over a GE plugin?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to add and toggle Google Maps over Google Earth Plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page, is that what you want?

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/mapsapi/index.html

Comment: That uses V2 of the Google Maps API, which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this utility library that allows you to combine Google Earth and Maps: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/